# Laravel database stored sessions

Tags: php, laravel, session

When a user logs in I am wanting to create a cookie that holds the session ID, this cookie with then get sent with every request, it will 1) check the user is authenitcated and 2) track events the user has done, however after the initial creation I am struggling to add new content to the payload stored in the database.

This is what I am trying,

```php
$payload = [
    'current_qestionnaire' => $request->qestionnaire_id,
    'current_question' => $request->question_id,
    'current_score' => $request->score
];

\Session::put('user.questionnaire', $payload);
\Session::save();
```

So basically the above I am trying to save 3 bits of data in a new object/array within the session and then save that to the users current row in database (something I assume is done automagically?).

Am I doing something wrong, how do I go about adding new data to an existing session row in the database?

Answer (score 0):

1. Session will be store in file by default or by your define with `SESSION_DRIVER` in `.env`
2. You only to call this to save to session `session(['user.questionnaire' => $payload])`

Comment: I understand that I need to change the `SESSION_DRIVER` my question was how I update an existing payload in an existing row.

Comment: Update here is rewrite value of your existing row